# Myth of Soma MMO game Bot - Memory Address for Items on floor contains garbage and constantly changing info

Tags: mmo

I've been coding a bot for a relatively small MMO, mainly as a hobby to challenge my own skills and learn something new.

I've overcome many challenges and have successfully built a bot which hunts monsters in the game and manages itself. However i've been unable to find the memory addresses for items on the floor. Using cheat engine, I find that the name of the item is stored more than 15 times around pockets of memory, when I pickup the item and place another down, some of these addresses will change to the new item's name, but the others will all change to garbage information which includes other text on the screen too such as whats going on in the chat.

Sometimes these pockets of memory addresses seem to actually change to the values of the item, then they quickly change again to garbage.

Is this some sort of scrambling anti-cheat? I can't imagine so since it is a very old and small game. It is called myth of soma.

I once found an address whcih always showed the first item on the floor, but I couldn't find any others and since then i've never found this address again.

This is an isometric game where each item on the floor is assigned coords. Would anyone have some advice for me in this area? I'd like to be able to reverse engineer the memory addresses for these items.

Comment: I would guess some of the pockets don't actually belong to the item but are just for displaying of the name? Like, let's say one of them is the label of a hover popup or something?

Comment: Yes it displays text at the time, but it sometimes seems to show data that isnt on screen. I've spent many hours search for the items on the floor. The game naturally see players, monsters,npcs as entities and places them in an address, then the offsets of that address are all of different stats for the entity, such as map coordinates, health etc. However I can't find such a thing for items and the one time I found something that stuck, it only showed the name and the durability of the item, nothing for coordinates. I was hoping someone more experienced in this reverse engineering could help.

Comment: Hmmm... what if the name isn't actually part of the item, but is derived from some id/attributes? If you have reverse engineered coordinates for the npcs etc before, maybe try to look for the right coordinates rather than the name of the item?

Comment: This is one of the problems, the coordinates are everywhere, they keep appearing in these random places then disappearing again replaced with garbage. I'll try again.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference for anybody. I finally solved this problem by creating a second cache array. By copying the data from the first into the second, if it exists but then also adding a cache timer to each row. If the data disappears from the main array, the timer cache timer will keep the data alive until it runs out.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this comment (4 years later!).  I also did development for this game back in the day so it was interesting to read about your solution.